# urllib2.urlopen to open download link

Tags: python, urllib2

i am trying to download data from a site with this code

```
import urllib2

source = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=WRPUPUS2&f=W").read()
open("http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=WRPUPUS2&f=W", "wb").write(source)
```

and keep getting the following error,

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'http://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=WRPUPUS2&f=W'
```

I am a little confused.

Comment: Do you really want to **write** to `http://...`?

Answer (score 0):

Python thinks `/` is directory so obviously that directory does not exist, it is also not valid using `/'s` in a filename on unix.

You could replace the `/` with another character like a `.`: and your code will run fine

```
with open("www.eia.gov.dnav.pet.hist.LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=WRPUPUS2&f=W", "wb") as f:
    f.write(source)
```